# Getting specific data from an object C#

Tags: c#, gridview, onclick, uwp

I'm busy with a UWP app that uses a gridview as a category page. I've put a OnClick listener for when one of the the grid items is clicked, and it works. The result is an object which contains the imageURL and imageText.

This is where the problem starts, I need to access the object and retrieve the imagetext, I've tried converting it using various methods but nothing seems to want to work.

Here is the output of the clicked item, which is correct.
[image: output of the clicked item]

This is currently my latest attempt, which simply passes "an object of this type cannot be converted"

```
private void CategoryItem_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            object output = e.ClickedItem;
            //string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)e.ClickedItem).Cast<object>()
                                 //.Select(x => x.ToString())
                                 //.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: use var instead of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`as` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) to cast the `object` to a `Wiin.MainPage.MyImage`:

```
private void CategoryItem_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    MyImage output = e.ClickedItem as MyImage;
    if (output == null) return; // the clicked item was not of the expected type
    string text = output.ImageText;
    string url = output.ImageUrl;
}
```

Your debugger shows that the `object` in `e.ClickedItem` *is* a `MyImage` instance, so the cast should work.

---

In case the `MyImage` type is a *value* type (a `struct`), the `as` operator won't work. You'd need to cast directly then:

```
MyImage output = (MyImage)e.ClickedItem;
```

But this cast will throw an `InvalidCastException` if `e.ClickedItem` contains an instance of a different type. You might check the type before casting using `is`:

```
if (!e.ClickedItem is MyImage) return;
```